# Zotero error in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, zotero

I installed Zotero standalone in 12.10 64-bit. Some problems which I managed to fix. The one that remains is an error saying

> openoffice.org could not communicate with Zotero. make sure zotero standalone or Firefox are open and set to an online state and try again

That's when I click any button in the Zotero toolbar in LibreOffice. Firefox doesn't open with a the plugin installed and a working internet connection. The Zotero troubleshooting which mentions this error was of no help to me. I find reports about this bug going back as far as 2009 but I haven't found anything of help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10. Actually the solution is quite simple.
Just go to the menu TOOLS>OPTIONS and search for the java section. There select the JRE installed, press OK, restart and thats all.

Comment: This suggestion worked for me on debian Stretch with the packages from the distribution (libreoffice, zotero-standalone, …). I had to click on my JRE in Libreoffice / tools / options / advanced. Then restart both zotero-standalone and libreoffice.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same trouble. This is my system:

- Linux Mint 13 with MATE 64 bit
- Zotero Standalone 3.0.8
- Libreoffice 3.5.4.2 (included with Linux Mint).

That configuration would not work with Zotero. The error was `"openoffice.org could not communicate with Zotero."`

## Solution

- Use package manager to completely remove Libreoffice.
- Download the latest version from [documentfoundation.org](http://documentfoundation.org).
- Unzip it and install it per the *Readme* text file. It will ask you to open the Libreoffice folders with your terminal, then run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` two times - once in the *DEBS* folder and once in the *Desktop Integration* folder.

Hope this helps! Like you I had no luck with this at all until I did this re-install of Libreoffice.